# Bypassing socket connections in node.js

Tags: node.js, tcp

I'm working in a project where we need to connect clients to devices behind LAN networks.

Brief description: there are "devices" connected, in a home for example, under a LAN created by a router. These devices create a full webserver, operating under linux, and using nodejs as the backend implementation language. They also have access to Internet, through the public IP of the router. On the other side, there are clients which can choose to which device to connect to.

The goal is to connect the clients with the webServer created by any device.

Up to now, my idea is to try to implement something similar to how TeamViewer works. As I understand, Teamviewer has a central server, which the agents connect to. When an agent connects to the central server, this one gets hold of the TCP connection, keeping it alive. When another client wants to access to the first client, the server bypasses both TCP connections. That way the server acts like a proxy, where it additionally routes the TCP connections. This also allows to connect to clients under LAN or firewalls (because the connections are created always from the clients).

If this is correct, what I would like to implement is a central server, in nodejs as well, which manages a pool of socket connections coming from the different active devices, and when a client wants to connect to one specific device, the server bypasses the incoming TCP connection of the client with the already existing connection of the device.

What I first would like to know is if this is possible in nodejs. My idea is to keep the device connections alive, so clients can inmediately connect to them, creating some sort of pool of device connections.

If implemented in C, I guess I could get hold of the socket descriptor, keeping it alive, and bypassing it to the incoming client request. But in nodejs I can't seem to find any modules that manage TCP connections.

Are there any high level npm packages which do this function? Else, is it possible to use lower level modules (like net) which have those functionalities.

Ideally I would like to implement it with high level modules (express), but if it's not possible, I could always rewrite the server using low level modules.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most of these types of apps use something like STUN (I assume TeamViewer does too), but that only works well with UDP AFAIK. I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mildred/b803e48801f9cdd8a4a8) that investigates TCP NAT traversal using STUN, perhaps it's useful.

Comment: Thanks @robertklep. That link is really useful. I'll take a look also to STUN servers, maybe that's the simplest way to implement it.